# Selenium Webdriver Cassing Issue C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am calling a method in my code that is populating customer information. At one particular point .sendkey is populating a zipcode text field. The program in which I am automating does CASSing as to pre populate the city and state fields which is fine but it causes a NoSuchElementException on the web elements there after. I tried a sleep but it occurs before the CASSing. Please advise how I can handle this (code syntax preferrably)

Comment: If someone is going to downgrade my question please explain. I've tried researching the cassing issue and cannot find a solution for handling this.

Comment: Honestly no idea what you are trying to say. What do you mean by "cassing"? Show us the code you wrote. Tell us where exactly the error occurs and more info on the error itself...

Comment: What is CASSing and need to see your code

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard. There was a postback issue in the application that was actually causing the issue. This is now resolved.